DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);.LAST_NAME) in((?,?,?);<is_not_null_token>, DRIVER=4.25.13
I am working on migrating the spring boot app to 3.X ,and facing facing issue while instering record in DB2.
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "emp")
public class Emp(){

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmpPersonalDetails empPersonalDetails;
  
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMP_DEPT", length = 10)
    @Length(max = 10, message = "The EMP DEPT must be less than 10 characters")
private String empDept;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "EMP_DESIGNATION", length = 10)
    @Length(max = 10, message = "The EMP DEPT must be less than 10 characters")
private String empDesignation;


}




@Embeddable
@Data
public class EmpPersonalDetails (){

   @NotNull
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", length = 10)
    @Length(max = 10, message = "The FIRST NAME must be less than 10 characters")
private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", length = 10)
    @Length(max = 10, message = "The LAST NAME must be less than 10 characters")
private String lastName;


}

Repository class-
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<EMP, EmpPersonalDetails > {
}

pom.xml has below dependency
    <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </parent>
    
    <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
               <version>3.1.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>6.2.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>db2jcc4</version>
        </dependency>

Calling repository save method-
  @Autowired
  private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository ;

Emp emp = new Emp();
emp.setEmpDept("Maths");
emp.setEmpDesignation("Professor");

EmpPersonalDetails empPersonalDetails  = new EmpPersonalDetails ();
empPersonalDetails.setFirstName("Mark");
empPersonalDetails.setLastName("Wood");

emp.setEmpPersonalDetails(empPersonalDetails);

employeeRepository .saveAndFlush(emp)

JPA- Hibernate is generating query like below and it is failing with below error-
 select q1_0.EMP_DEPT,q1_0.EMP_DESIGNATION,q1_0.EMP_DEPT,q1_0.FIRST_NAME,q1_0.LAST_NAME from EMP q1_0 where (q1_0.FIRST_NAME,q1_0.LAST_NAME) in((?,?))


DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);.LAST_NAME) in((?,?,?);<is_not_null_token>, DRIVER=4.25.13
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: JDBC exception executing SQL

I want hibernate to generate simple query with and operator, please help on this, and why it is generting IN query
select q1_0.EMP_DEPT,q1_0.EMP_DESIGNATION,q1_0.EMP_DEPT,q1_0.FIRST_NAME,q1_0.LAST_NAME from EMP q1_0 where q1_0.FIRST_NAME =? q1_0.LAST_NAME=?


your db2 jdbc driver version 4.25.13 is out of support. Try db2 jdbc driver version 4.33.31  (or higher if available , download it from https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/db2-jdbc-driver-versions-and-downloads ) .
